# При вызове деструктора в строке "delete data" выбрасывается исключение

Tags: c++, исключения, vector

Написал свою реализацию `vector` с функциями, которые мне были нужны. При вызове деструктора в строке `delete data` выбрасывается исключение. При попытке продолжить `Crt` выдает ошибку:

> Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer (block).

Уже голову сломал, а все равно не пойму, где я налажал.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class MyVector {
    int* Data;
    int size;
public:
    MyVector() {
        size = 0;
    }
    MyVector(int Msize) {
        size = Msize;
        Data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Data[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    ~MyVector() {
        delete Data;
    }
    int& operator[] (int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < size) {
            return Data[index];
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "ошибка доступа" << std::endl;
            return Data[0];
        }
    }
    int& operator[] (int index) const {
        if (index >= 0 && index < size) {
            return Data[index];
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "ошибка доступа" << std::endl;
            return Data[0];
        }
    }
    int Size() {
        return size;
    }
    void push_back(int Number) {
        size++;
        int* tempData = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            tempData[i] = Data[i];
        }
        delete[] Data;
        tempData[size - 1] = Number;
        Data = tempData;
    }
    void pop_back() {
        size--;
        int* tempData = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            tempData[i] = Data[i];
        }
        delete[] Data;
        Data = tempData;
    }
};
```

Класс который использует `MyVector`:

```
#pragma once
#include "MyVector.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class BigInt
{
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, BigInt &Number);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const BigInt &Number);
    void Input();
    void Output();
    void Add(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2);
    void Sub(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2);
    void Mul(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2);
    void Div(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator + (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator = (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator - (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator * (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator / (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator += (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator -= (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator *= (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator /= (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator - ();
    bool operator > (BigInt Number2);
    bool operator < (BigInt Number2);
    bool operator >= (BigInt Number2);
    bool operator <= (BigInt Number2);
    bool operator == (BigInt Number2);
    bool operator != (BigInt Number2);
    BigInt& operator++ ();
    BigInt operator++ (int);
    BigInt& operator-- ();
    BigInt operator-- (int);
    BigInt(long long xxx);
    BigInt();
    ~BigInt();
private:
    int length;
    void SearchZero();
    const int ChunkSize = 1;
    MyVector Number;
    int Sign;
};
```

`.сpp класса:`

```
#include "BigInt.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyVector.h"
using namespace std;

void BigInt::Input()
{
    bool correct = false;
    string str;
    while (!correct)
    {
        cout << "Введите корректное число:" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        correct = true;
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            if (((str[0] < 48) || (str[0] > 57)) && (str[0] != 45)) {
                correct = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (((str[i] < 49) || (str[i] > 57)) && (str[i] != 45))
                    {
                        correct = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((str[i] < 48) || (str[i] > 57))
                    {
                        correct = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (str[0] == '-')
    {
        Sign = -1;
        str.erase(str.begin());
    }
    else
    {
        Sign = 1;
    }
    for (int i = str.length() - ChunkSize; i > 0; i -= ChunkSize)
    {
        Number.push_back(stoi(str.substr(i, ChunkSize)));
    }
    Number.push_back(stoi(str.substr(0, 1)));
    length = Number.Size();
}
void BigInt::Output()
{
    if (Sign == -1) {
        cout << '-';
    }
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << Number[i];
    }
    if (length == 0) {
        cout << 0;
    }
}

void BigInt::SearchZero() {
    length = Number.Size();
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (Number[i] != 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (Number[i] == 0) {
            Number.pop_back();
        }
    }
    length = Number.Size();
}

void BigInt::Add(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2)
{
    if ((Number1.Sign == 1) && (Number2.Sign == 1))
    {
        bool FirstIsBigger = false;
        if (Number1.length > Number2.length)
        {
            FirstIsBigger = true;
        }
        if (FirstIsBigger)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Number1.length; i++)
            {
                if (i < Number2.length)
                {
                    Number1.Number[i] = Number1.Number[i] + Number2.Number[i];
                }
                if (Number1.Number[i] >= 10)
                {
                    Number1.Number[i] = Number1.Number[i] - 10;
                    if (i == Number1.length - 1) {
                        Number1.Number.push_back(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        Number1.Number[i + 1] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            Number = Number1.Number;
            length = Number1.length;
            this->SearchZero();
            Sign = Number1.Sign;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Number2.length; i++)
            {
                if (i < Number1.length)
                {
                    Number2.Number[i] = Number1.Number[i] + Number2.Number[i];
                }
                if (Number2.Number[i] >= 10)
                {
                    Number2.Number[i] = Number2.Number[i] - 10;
                    if (i == Number2.length - 1) {
                        Number2.Number.push_back(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        Number2.Number[i + 1] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            Number = Number2.Number;
            length = Number2.length;
            this->SearchZero();
            Sign = Number2.Sign;
        }
    }
    if ((Number1.Sign == -1) && (Number2.Sign == 1))
    {
        Number1.Sign = 1;
        this->Sub(Number2, Number1);
    }
    if ((Number1.Sign == 1) && (Number2.Sign == -1))
    {
        Number2.Sign = 1;
        this->Sub(Number1, Number2);
    }
    if ((Number1.Sign == -1) && (Number2.Sign == -1))
    {
        Number1.Sign = 1;
        Number2.Sign = 1;
        this->Add(Number1, Number2);
        this->Sign = -1;
    }
}
void BigInt::Sub(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2)
{
    if ((Number1.Sign == 1) && (Number2.Sign == 1))
    {
        bool FirstIsBigger = false;
        if (Number1.length > Number2.length)
        {
            FirstIsBigger = true;
        }
        if (Number1.length == Number2.length) {
            int countDischarge = Number1.length - 1;
            while (countDischarge >= 0) {
                if (Number1.Number[countDischarge] != Number2.Number[countDischarge]) {
                    if (Number1.Number[countDischarge] > Number2.Number[countDischarge]) {
                        FirstIsBigger = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        FirstIsBigger = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                countDischarge--;
            }
        }
        if (FirstIsBigger)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Number1.length; i++)
            {
                if (i < Number2.length)
                {
                    Number1.Number[i] = Number1.Number[i] - Number2.Number[i];
                }
                if (Number1.Number[i] < 0)
                {
                    Number1.Number[i] = Number1.Number[i] + 10;
                    Number1.Number[i + 1] -= 1;
                }
            }
            Number = Number1.Number;
            length = Number1.length;
            this->SearchZero();
            Sign = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Number2.length; i++)
            {
                if (i < Number1.length)
                {
                    Number2.Number[i] = Number2.Number[i] - Number1.Number[i];
                }
                if (Number2.Number[i] < 0)
                {
                    Number2.Number[i] = Number2.Number[i] + 10;
                    Number2.Number[i + 1] -= 1;
                }

            }
            Number = Number2.Number;
            length = Number2.length;
            this->SearchZero();
            if (length != 0) {
                Sign = -1;
            }
            else {
                Sign = 1;
            }

        }
    }
    if ((Number1.Sign == -1) && (Number2.Sign == 1))
    {
        Number1.Sign = 1;
        this->Add(Number1, Number2);
        Sign = -1;
    }
    if ((Number1.Sign == 1) && (Number2.Sign == -1))
    {
        Number2.Sign = 1;
        this->Add(Number1, Number2);
    }
    if ((Number1.Sign == -1) && (Number2.Sign == -1))
    {
        Number2.Sign = 1;
        this->Add(Number2, Number1);
    }
}

void BigInt::Mul(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2) {
    int maxLength = 0;
    bool FirstIsBigger = false;
    if (Number1.length <= Number2.length) {
        maxLength = Number2.length;
        FirstIsBigger = false;
    }
    else {
        maxLength = Number1.length;
        FirstIsBigger = true;
    }
    MyVector tempNumber(2 * maxLength);
    MyVector temp(2 * maxLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * maxLength; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Size(); i++) {
            temp[i] = 0;
        }
        if (FirstIsBigger) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Number2.length; j++) {
                if (i < maxLength) {
                    temp[j] = Number2.Number[j] * Number1.Number[i];
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < Number2.length; j++) {
                while (temp[j] >= 10) {
                    temp[j + 1] += 1;
                    temp[j] -= 10;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < Number1.length; j++) {
                if (i < maxLength) {
                    temp[j] = Number1.Number[j] * Number2.Number[i];
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < Number2.length; j++) {
                while (temp[j] > 10) {
                    temp[j + 1] += 1;
                    temp[j] -= 10;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            for (int m = 2 * maxLength - 2; m >= 0; m--) {
                temp[m + 1] = temp[m];
                if (m == 0) {
                    temp[m] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * maxLength; i++)
        {
            if (i < 2 * maxLength)
            {
                tempNumber[i] = tempNumber[i] + temp[i];
            }
            if (tempNumber[i] >= 10) {
                tempNumber[i + 1] += 1;
                tempNumber[i] -= 10;
            }
        }
    }
    Number = tempNumber;
    if (Number1.Sign != Number2.Sign) {
        Sign = -1;
    }
    else {
        Sign = 1;
    }
    this->SearchZero();
    length = Number.Size();
}

void BigInt::Div(BigInt Number1, BigInt Number2) {
    if (Number2 == 0) {
        cout << "ошибка деления" << endl;
        *this = Number1;
    }
    else {
        int temp;
        *this = BigInt(0);
        if (Number1.Sign != Number2.Sign) {
            temp = -1;
        }
        else {
            temp = 1;
        }
        Number1.Sign = 1; Number2.Sign = 1;
        Number1 -= Number2;
        while (Number1 >= 0) {
            ++*this;
            Number1 -= Number2;
        }
        this->Sign = temp;
    }
}

BigInt &BigInt::operator+ (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Add(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator - (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Sub(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator * (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Mul(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator / (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Div(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator /= (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Div(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt &BigInt::operator*= (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Mul(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt &BigInt::operator+= (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Add(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator -= (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Sub(*this, Number2);
    return *this;
}

bool BigInt::operator == (BigInt Number2) {
    BigInt temp = *this;
    temp -= Number2;
    int i = temp.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        if (temp.Number[i] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
        i--;
    }
    return true;
}

bool BigInt::operator != (BigInt Number2) {
    if (*this == Number2) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool BigInt::operator > (BigInt Number2) {
    BigInt temp = *this;
    temp -= Number2;
    if (temp == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (temp.Sign == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

bool BigInt::operator >= (BigInt Number2) {
    BigInt temp = *this;
    temp -= Number2;
    if (temp == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (temp.Sign == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

bool BigInt::operator < (BigInt Number2) {
    if (*this >= Number2) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool BigInt::operator <= (BigInt Number2) {
    if (*this > Number2) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator ++ () {
    BigInt Number = 1;
    this->Add(*this, Number);
    return *this;
}

BigInt BigInt::operator ++ (int) {
    BigInt temp = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator-- () {
    BigInt Number = 1;
    this->Sub(*this, Number);
    return *this;
}

BigInt BigInt::operator-- (int) {
    BigInt temp = *this;
    --(*this);
    return temp;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator - () {
    this->Sign *= -1;
    return *this;
}

BigInt& BigInt::operator = (BigInt Number2) {
    this->Sign = Number2.Sign;
    this->Number = Number2.Number;
    this->length = Number2.length;
    return *this;
}

BigInt::BigInt(long long xxx)
{
    if (xxx < 0)
    {
        Sign = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        Sign = 1;
    }
    xxx *= Sign;
    int ost;
    while (xxx != 0)
    {
        ost = xxx % 10;
        Number.push_back(ost);
        xxx /= 10;
    }
    length = Number.Size();
}

BigInt::BigInt()
{

}

BigInt::~BigInt() {
    
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const BigInt &Number) {
    if (Number.Sign == -1) {
        out << '-';
    }
    for (int i = Number.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        out << Number.Number[i];
    }
    if (Number.length == 0) {
        out << 0;
    }
    return out;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, BigInt &Number) {
    bool correct = false;
    string str;
    while (!correct)
    {
        cout << "Введите корректное число:" << endl;
        in >> str;
        correct = true;
        if (str.length() == 1) {
            if (((str[0] < 48) || (str[0] > 57)) && (str[0] != 45)) {
                correct = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (((str[i] < 49) || (str[i] > 57)) && (str[i] != 45))
                    {
                        correct = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((str[i] < 48) || (str[i] > 57))
                    {
                        correct = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (str[0] == '-')
    {
        Number.Sign = -1;
        str.erase(str.begin());
    }
    else
    {
        Number.Sign = 1;
    }
    for (int i = str.length() - Number.ChunkSize; i > 0; i -= Number.ChunkSize)
    {
        Number.Number.push_back(stoi(str.substr(i, Number.ChunkSize)));
    }
    Number.Number.push_back(stoi(str.substr(0, 1)));
    Number.length = Number.Number.Size();
    return in;
}
```

`main():`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BigInt.h"
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    BigInt N1, N2;
    cin >> N2 >> N1;
    cout << "Результат:" << endl;
    cout << N2/N1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо вам за ваш вопрос! И форматирование текста, и ошибка - всё как в детстве, когда после победы на олимпиаде по программированию почти тридцать лет назад мне подарили первое издание книги Страуструпа. В противной обложке грязного цвета. Потом я уже сам купил второе издание весёлого оранжевого цвета и читал взахлёб ))

Так вот. Об ошибках. Все проходили по этим граблям, я уверен.

1. Вы не инициализируете память в конструкторе, а потом освобождаете её в деструкторе. Добавьте хотя бы вот так:

```
MyVector::MyVector() {
    size = 0;
    Data = 0;
}

MyVector::~MyVector() {
    if (Data != 0)
        delete Data;
}
```

2. У вас нет конструктора копирования. Поэтому каждый раз, когда вы передаёте `BigInt` не как ссылку, на стеке создается копия с теми же значениями `size` и -- **внимание** -- указателя `Data`.

После завершения вызова функции временный объект удаляется и (барабанная дробь) для него вызывается деструктор. То есть после того, как вы, скажем, вызвали `Add(num1,num2)` массивы `num1.Data` и `num2.Data` уже освобождены в деструкторах объектов-копий. Потом `num1` и `num2` в свою очередь будут освобождены, деструктор попытается освободить памать, а она уже того, свободна. И привет, `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

3. У вас нет оператора присваивания для MyVector. Поэтому каждый раз, когда вы присваиваете `Number = other.Number`, указатель на данные, существовавшие в текущем объекте `BigInt`, стираются (утечка памяти, хрен бы с ней), и создаётся **второй** указатель на `other.Number.Data`. Когда либо `other`, либо текущий объект будут прибраны, второй указатель будет указывать в никуда. Соответственно, при удалении второго объекта будет `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` или какие ещё радостные ситуации.

Как исправить.

1. Сделать простой и наивный способ: копирующий конструктор, копирующее присваивание.

```
MyVector::MyVector(const MyVector& other) {
    size = other.size;
    if (size == 0) {
        Data = 0;
    } else {
        Data = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Data[i] = other.Data[i];
        }
    }
}

MyVector& MyVector::operator=(const MyVector& other) {
    if (Data != 0)
        delete Data;
    size = other.size;
    Data = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Data[i] = other.Data[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Работает.

```
Введите корректное число:
1234567
Введите корректное число:
1234
Результат:
1000
```

Заодно пройти по коду и везде, где можно, поменять типы аргументов с `BigInt` на `const BigInt&` - это радикально сократит число копирований.

2. Чуть менее наивный. Добавить в `MyVector` счётчик ссылок: при каждом присваивании будет счётчик увеличивать, при каждой деструкции уменьшать. Как только счётчик дойдёт до нуля - можно освобождать память. Примеров в интернете много.
3. Правильный. Поставить, наконец, на полку издание Стауструпа тридцатилетней давности, и прочитать что-нибудь более современное, где разбирают `std::vector` и `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyVector() {
    size = 0;
    Data = NULL;
}

BigInt::BigInt()
{
    length = 0;
    Sign = 1;
}
```

---

В этой строчке что происходит?

```
this->Number = Number2.Number;
```

Comment: По моему, прекрасный ответ! Коротко и по делу. Я бы на месте автора вопроса его отметил.

Comment: Я поправил, но ,к сожалению, проблему это не решило...

Comment: @S.H. Семнадцать лет назад я провел чудесную неделю, пытаясь найти подобную ошибку.

Comment: > Я поправил, но ,к сожалению, проблему это не решило - а вот это уже интересно...

Comment: @Legida Пора показать код, который использует `MyVector`.

Comment: @Igor он не вмещается в коммент...

Comment: @Legida И не надо вмещать его в "коммент". Под вопросом - ссылка "Править".

Comment: @Igor готово!!!

Comment: А не многого я попрошу, если попрошу добавить то, чтотут называют "минимальным примером, воспроизводящим ошибку"? Ну, какой нить main(), котрый вызываешь- и готво, ошибка! Спасибо заранее  за головоломку :-)

Comment: @S.H. Добавил main

Comment: @Igor Конструктор BigInt поправил, не помогло. В строчке происходит присваивание вектора объекта Number2.Number к Number объекта, к которому мы применили метод. P.S кстати, я подумал, что проблема в том, что стандартный оператор = в MyVector стоит перегрузить, и что, мейби, проблема в нем, но не помогло... 
`MyVector& operator = (MyVector Number) {
  size = Number.size;
  delete Data;
  Data = new int[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   Data[i] = Number.Data[i];
  }
  return *this;
 }`